# Shortening variable names in R

Tags: r, sna

I have a column called `pseudo_user_id` which is a long-character string. I want to create a Social Network with nodes and links to perform some analysis. However, these id's overlapped each other and made it unclear.

Is there any way to shorten them or map them into something equivalent so that my nodes look tidy?

```
user_pseudo_id
<chr>
ffb3f6fb93fa685ea4cddec45a0f8f22ab7ab2e7cd0b9ec02db08939a9c21151    
e7b30583d7028e807886fce1a867cd851f7f5787a738df86a319bce8f33de2bb    
a2a515b885697a9d138dde0e3564a062caa331acc7f3f54624c68af508a1677d    
...
```

[image: overlapped-labels]

Comment: What do you want to shorten them to? Or what do you want to replace them with? What ever you decide can probably be done.

Comment: Function `abbreviate` shortens elements of a character vector to their minimum length required to keep them unique.

Comment: @MrFlick, I would like to just keep the last 4 characters of the id.

Comment: Try: `as.numeric(as.factor(x))`

Comment: Or: `substr(x, nchar(x)-3, nchar(x))`

Comment: @zx8754, how can I apply this to an entire column?

Comment: x is your column. But how can you be sure that the last 4 chars will make them unique?

Comment: I  just want to shorten them so that are readable. Is there any other way without losing the uniqueness of the id?

Comment: Make a new ID, perhaps, `users <- (c(usr_id, usr_id, usr_id))`, `make.unique(strtrim(users, 10))
[1] "ffb3f6fb93"   "ffb3f6fb93.1" "ffb3f6fb93.2"`